# mvn release:prepare release:perform from docker image jenkins git credentials to docker image

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to release a project by using a service of a docker file that execute mvn release:prepare release:perform as stated below:
docker-compose.yml

```
 release:
    image: maven:alpine
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
      - .:/usr/src/mymaven
    working_dir: /usr/src/mymaven
    command: mvn -B release:prepare release:perform
```

Then in jenkins dsl pipeline

```
stage("Release") {
 steps {
     task "release"
     sh "docker-compose run --rm release"
 }
}
```

The problem i found was that i need not only to install git in the image which is not difficult, but also that i need jenkins git credentials to be copied to the image in order for the release plugin to push changes to git repo.

my questions:
Is this a good practice to release from a docker image, how is this frecuently done by devops ?
How can i copy jenkins credentials to the image temporarly?
Any useful links related to releasing from jenkins dsl?
Thanks,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

In a popular or official way in Docker you can use the [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) to handle the Usernames and passwords. But in my experience, I will use the [build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) to build a image through Jenkins and pass the username and password with arg to the dockerfile to build the image and execute the docker compose.